# Search all Expression text in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, sql-server-2014, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2014

I am working on a report which has many Expressions defined and would like to check all of these Expressions for the occurrence of some particular string - is this possible?

For example, I'd like to be able to identify all Expressions which contain the text `Round(` so that I can determine whether there's some unnecessary rounding being done.

Comment: If you don't want to it fully automated, you can simply download your report file (.rdl) from the server and open it in a simple editor (the file is in an xml-based layout) and search for "Round(". If this is what you search for, please tell me, then i'll convert this into an answer. If not, please be more precise how exactly you want the check to happen.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. If you want to submit as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do it fully automated, you can simply download your report file (.rdl) from the server and open it in a simple editor (the file is in an xml-based layout) and search for "Round(".